# Apache taking 2+ seconds to initially respond to GET request

Tags: windows, apache

This is on Windows 10. This is a website running on my own computer. Hitting the root index is instant, but opening /bugzilla takes ages. It takes the same amount of time regardless of whether I try my computer's IP address or 127.0.0.1 or localhost. The result I get is pretty much this:

[image]

Full httpd.conf on [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe9726b9241a6e187cd31e5d48f8a3d4)

I have wireshark but I'm not really sure how to use it...

Ping time for my computer's address

```
>ping 192.168.168.110

Pinging 192.168.168.110 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.168.110: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.110: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.110: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.110: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.168.110:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/66347/why-is-the-response-on-localhost-so-slow?

Comment: Sorry, editing this comment b/c i spoke too soon. I need to read that full thread.

Comment: Ping times aren't relevant, read the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not using PHP. I already have `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl` in my httpd.conf. I already have `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`. I added `<FilesMatch>` entries for .cgi and .pl to no effect. I can hit 192.168.168.110 in milliseconds tho, so you're probably right that this is the issue.

Comment: It's probably about the hostname.